# Python how to group by and get top 5 rows?

Tags: python, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

i have a data frame as below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Salary_Range": ['0-4999', '0-4999', '0-4999', '5000-7999', '5000-7999', '8000-14999', '8000-14999'],
  "Nationality_desc": ['India', 'India', 'Philippines', 'Pakistan', 'America', 'America', 'India'],
  "AgeGroup":['Adult','Adult','Young','Young','Senior','Senior','Adult'],
  "Amount":['10000','24000','45000','21200','43200','12300','54300'],
  "Category" :['Electrical','Electrical','Electrical','House','Toy','Car','House']})
```

i need to group by

- "Salary_Range"
- "Nationality_desc"
- "AgeGroup"
- "Category" (in the same order)

and get the sum of "Amount". Though its straightforward grouping, the challenge here is that i want to get this group values only for say Top 5 "Category" (In my data, though for a particular Salary_Range, we can take only Top 2, so we can consider Top 2 for my Toy dataset)

I wrote the below code, but i am not able to get only Top 2 "Category" , it gives all available "Category" .

```
   frame_mcc=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Salary_Range','Nationality_desc','AgeGroup','Category'],
                    values=['Amount'],aggfunc=[np.sum,len],fill_value=0)
```

The Amount here is for one year. i wanted it to be averaged for a month so the Sum of Amount has to be Divided by 12.

Also, how can i visualize this pivot (or) group by?

Top 5 (or) 2 : "CATEGORY" is by summing the "AMOUNT"

Comment: What would be the expected output for the data you posted?

Comment: expected output is the one i have given code for.. expect that instead of all the CATEGORY only TOP 2 CATEGORY shud come